# Bitbucket/Mercurial/Tortoise How do I add a folder to a Bitbucket repo?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

I'm working on a project with 2 other people and want to create separate folders for each of us in a Bitbucket repo.  I've tried creating the folders on my machine and pushing it up to the repo but this isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is this tagged `git`? It has nothing to do with it, if you want to create and use an `hg` repo...

Comment: I've added an answer for why creating the folders _probably_ didn't work (files are tracked, not folders), but I'm wondering if you really want folders anyway? If you are working collaboratively on a project, then you probably don't want user-specific files in the repo. If the folders are to store working versions of the main files (for example), then you should look into the branching mechanics of Mercurial.

Comment: Also, I've retagged, as (like with `git`) this doesn't have anything to do with `svn`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a folder, you need to create a file in that folder and add it to the repository, then you can push it.  Mercurial tracks changes to files, so if a folder has no "content" then it will not be tracked.

Say you had a base source file that you wanted in each directory (we'll call it `main.cpp`), you could create the folders like so:

```
$ mkdir folder1
$ mkdir folder2
$ hg st
```

Note that nothing is listed in response to the status, as there are no new files.

```
$ cp main.cpp folder1
$ cp main.cpp folder2
$ hg st
? folder1/main.cpp
? folder2/main.cpp
```

The above shows that adding files to the folders makes them "visible" to Mercurial.

```
$ hg add
$ hg st
+ folder1/main.cpp
+ folder2/main.cpp
```

Now the files are marked as added, and so when you commit they'll exist in the repository.

Note that the above was *an example* to demonstrate that you need files in a folder for it to be seen.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed.  I just put empty README files in the folders and now they're visible.  Thank you.

Comment: Yep, we often do a .ignore file so it's understood the empty directory is the desire. Usually to support tests clearly.